# what to know in order running Activity in extern application

Tags: android

I wonder if it's possbile, and if it is, what i`am suppose to know, in order to run an Activity in some application, while i am calling it from another application.

for example, now i am on Application A, and i want to run an Activity on Application B.
what parameters do i need to know in order to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how would you launch that activity...

If you want to tightly couple your intent from App A with the activity of App B, then you should be knowing the activity name and inturn the app name.  Eg: com.xxx.xxx.xxx

If you want to fire an intent with the action, Then you must provide the action name to the Intent and the intent filter for this action must be set in the activity of App B.

Comment: could you provide please some samples of both ways?
thank you.

Comment: Read through following links: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html